# How to create ExtJS elements with dynamic id ExtJs 3.0

Tags: javascript, extjs3

At a time in function need to pass with id and without id(null). Static it is working but how I will make this in dynamic? Here `winCreatePand` is model window id.

```js
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Generate',
    id: 'btnGenerate',
    width: 65,
    style: 'margin-left: 10px',
    handler: function() {
        PandDataProvider.GetPandId();
        PandDataProvider.GetPandId('winCreatePand');
    },
    scope: this
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set a `reference` on the button and make the view a `referenceHolder = true`? So, this applies to ExtJS 5+, so I am not sure why you are still using 3. Also, please provide a better; testable solution.

Comment: thanks Mr.Polywhirl, will you please post one demo?

Comment: If the author uses ExtJs v3, the `reference` property is not possible to use. It first appeared in ExtJs 5